# Unable to untar a file?

Tags: linux, unix, ftp, shell, tar

I have written a shellscript which tries to pull a tar file from an ftp server and untar it locally. I need to extract specific files from the tar archive. The filename of the tarfile contains a date; I need to be able to select a tar file based on this date.

`abc_myfile_$date.tar` is the format of the file I am pulling from the ftp server.

My current code looks like this:

```
for host in ftpserver
do
ftp -inv host <<END_SCRIPT
user username password
prompt
cd remotepath
lcd localpath
mget *myfile_$date*.tar
quit
END_SCRIPT
done

for next in `ls localpath/*.tar`
do
tar xvf $next *required_file_in_tar_file*.dat
done
```

when i run the script am not able to untar the files

I am able to get a single tar file from the ftp server only if I mention the exact name of that file. I would like to get a file which has `myfile_$date` in its name. After this I would like to extract it to a local path to get the specified files in that tar file whose names consist of my `required_files`.

Comment: i'm sorry, but is this PHP? or What language is this in?

Comment: shell script....................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the `.tar` file, but decompress it with `z` option. Compressed files (those that require `z`) normally have `.tar.gz` prefix. Try

```
tar xvf $next *required_file_in_tar_file*.dat
```

Comment: when i execute this command in command line its working perfectly.

but in script its not working
tar: my_required_file_in_tar_file_123.dat : not found in archieve

but that file is inside the archieve...

Comment: have you considered quoting the second parameter (the one with asterisks)?

Comment: i have written same as u mentioned and tried with other types .
am able to do all this in command line
but when i run the script am not able to untar the files.

Comment: "not able" saying what? (BTW, why don't you `for next in localpath/*` instead of spawning yet another ls? which, under certain circumstances may pollute your tar names with colorizing escape sequences).

Comment: after ftp if i put 
cd localpath
am able to get un tar the required files....

thank u....

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you want to use wildcards for the file name that you're getting from the server you need to use mget instead of get. Wildcard file expansion (the *) does not work for the get command.
Once you have pulled the file the tar operation will work as expected, most modern versions of linux/bsd have a 'smart' tar, which doesn't need the 'z' command to specify that the tar file is compressed - they'll figure out that the tarball is compressed on their own and uncompress it automatically, providing the appropriate compression/decompression tool is on the system (bzip2 for .jz files, gzip for .gz files).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, but does the FTP protocol not have a command `mget` if you want to download multiple files? (instead of `get`)